# MATLAB linear algebra

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I have, for example:

```
p1 = [a;b];

p2 = [c;d];

T1 = [e,f;
      g,h];

T2 = [i,l;
      m,n];
```

and:

```
R = [T1*p1, T2*p2];
```

That gives me a 2x2 matrix:
I'm searching a way to do:

```
R=T*P;
```

simply building a matrix T with T1 and T2 and a matrix P with p1 and p2.
For linear algebra it seems impossible considering that T can only be 4x2 or 2x4 and P only 2x2, 1x4 or 4x1. I can't obtain a 2x2 matrix for the rule NxP*PxM = NxM.
Any ideas?

Comment: Use `p1`, and `p2` (and zeros) to create a 4x2 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below formula to the perform the concatenation with multiplication instead of language constructs:

[image: Matrix concatenation via multiplication].

So your matrix `P` needs to be padded with zeros.
Instead of using the `zeros` function, you can use the `blkdiag` function which determine the zero padding internally:

```
P = blkdiag(p1,p2);
T = [T1,T2];
R = T*P;
```

However, unless the number of vectors you wish to perform this operation on will increase, I think the direct concatenation is best both in clarity and performance.
If the number is expected to grow, then I would use `sparse` either on `p1`, `p2`, ... or on the `blkdiag` call such that needless multiplications are kept to a minimum.